# Applying lambda function to Dataframe to get the datatypes

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use the lambda function to get the data types of the columns in a `pandas` dataframe. Let's say that my dataframe is df. I wrote the following code

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.dtype)
```

So if `df` has numeric columns, this command should return `'int64'` for those columns. But when I run the code for one dataframe I have, I just see `object` returned as the type. Why is this behavior ?

Comment: Have you tried `df.info()` instead of using apply? It does exactly what you need. And `dtype` indeed should work as expected, so perhaps not all of your values are in int64?

Comment: It means they are not treated as numbers and you need to convert (with `pd.to_numeric` or `.astype('int')`. You can get the same result with `df.dtypes` by the way.

Comment: When I check the dtype of the individual columns, using `df[column_name].dtype` , I do get `dtype('int64')`. So there are stored as integers. There is one column, which is the names of the movies, so its individual dtype is object

Comment: Sorry I cannot reproduce that problem. Is it possible that you are misinterpreting the dtype of returning object? The Series that holds dtypes is of type "object" because dtype names are string. Can you post the output?

Comment: Hello ayhan,   The dataset is [link](https://github.com/shian48263/dataquest/blob/master/Data%20Visualization/Guided%20Project-%20Visualizing%20Pixar's%20Roller%20Coaster/PixarMovies.csv) I called this dataset pixar_movies and ran the following command `pixar_movies.apply(lambda x: x.dtype)`

Comment: And the output is [link](http://paste.ofcode.org/DakLgg2FwQSvvzdL9JgFsg)

Comment: Is `[pixar_movies[x].dtype for x in pixar_movies.columns]` what you want? I don't see why `pixar_movies.dtypes` wouldn't work for you, as ayhan posted. Did you want `pixar_movies.dtypes.tolist()` maybe? I think the matter here is why do you want an apply function to yield metadata that can be accessed thorugh direct methods

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shian48263/dataquest/master/Data%20Visualization/Guided%20Project-%20Visualizing%20Pixar's%20Roller%20Coaster/PixarMovies.csv")`

Comment: Try the above code and `df.dtypes`. I have int's in that output.

Comment: vmg, ayhan... I think your approach works. I was looking for some complicated solution...

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is due to the fact that the columns are fed one by one as pandas Series in the apply() function. So, when you do dtype of a Series object, it wouldn't return an int or float or any other datatype (even though df.dtypes and df.info() show current datatypes). Rather, it will return an object datatype because you asked pandas to tell you the dtype of a Series 'object'. For Example,

```
tmp = pd.DataFrame({'v1':[1,2,3], 'v2':['a','b','c'], 'v3':[1.1,2.34,3.66]})
tmp.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, object), axis = 0)
v1    True
v2    True
v3    True
dtype: bool

tmp.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, pd.Series), axis = 0)
v1    True
v2    True
v3    True
dtype: bool

tmp.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, (int, float)), axis = 0)
v1    False
v2    False
v3    False
dtype: bool

tmp.dtypes
v1      int64
v2     object
v3    float64
dtype: object
```

However, there is a trick to getting the desired result. Instead of doing isinstance() of the entire Series object, you can use the first value of the Series and then do isinstance() of that value. This will work because the datatype of a column, even if it contains mixed type values, will be the same as the datatype of one of the values of that column.

```
tmp['v4'] = ['ad23','fg563',-999]
tmp.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x[0], (int, float)), axis = 0)
v1      True
v2      False
v3      True
v4      False
dtype: bool
```

Hope that clarified your doubt! Of course, as others have suggested, you can use df.dtypes or df.info() to get the column datatype information. But if you want to write a custom code, where you use an if-else condition in the apply() to check on column datatype, this solution would be helpful.